# How can we compine JAX-WS and JAX-RS together?

Tags: jax-ws, jax-rs

Apache CFX can do the task.But i would like to combine it without any spring depedencides.Thank you in advance !

Comment: It should be possible with CFX — it does have some support for non-Spring usage — but why would you want to do that when the majority of documentation is for doing so _with_ Spring? (For the record, I've got an app that does JAX-WS and JAX-RS together, but it's CFX over Spring so I don't know if my experiences will help you.)

Comment: And the tricky part is that you describe your webapp in completely different ways in the two architecture styles. You might be able to share one or two methods if you're lucky I suppose…

Answer (score 5):

Both JAX-WS and JAX-RS are part of [Java EE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html). So you can build an application that exports both JAX-WS and JAX-RS interfaces without using Spring. For an introduction see the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html).

**Note:** JAX-WS and JAX-RS implement *very* different concepts. While JAX-WS is basically SOAP, JAX-RS is an implementation of the REST concept. I recommend to *not* mix both concepts as far as APIs are concerned. [SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/soap/info) is about method calls while [REST](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rest/info) is about Resources and Representations.